# Interpolate a one-dimensional vector to specified new size in R

Tags: r, interpolation

How do I interpolate, lets say a 10 numeric list/vector in R to a specified new size (eg. size=6)?

```
ls <- c(1:10) # size 10
```

Resulting in something like:

```
ls_interp <- ... # interpolate

> ls_interp
[1] 1 2 4 6 8 10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```r
ls_interp <- approx( x, n=6 )$x
ls_interp
```

It outputs: `[1]  1.0  2.8  4.6  6.4  8.2 10.0`

In reality it gives you back both x's and y's (but you only really need the one in this case)

Comment: Ah thanks, I tried with approxfun and it needed 2 inputs. This works great thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Another option is using `seq` (but I believe [`approx` method by @Sirius](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67020687/12158757) is better)

```
> seq(min(ls), max(ls), length.out = 6)
[1]  1.0  2.8  4.6  6.4  8.2 10.0
```

or

```
> min(ls) + (length(ls) - 1) / 5 * (seq(6) - 1)
[1]  1.0  2.8  4.6  6.4  8.2 10.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the compliment! This answer deffinitely belongs in the picture too.